# Show small icons in Xcode object picker?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.6

I may be grasping at straws here, but is there any way to shrink the icon size in this editor panel in Xcode?

[image]

It seems my options are either huge list rows or big icons without labels.

Comment: you can't change the size once you place it?

Comment: I'm talking about the size of the icons in the list, so I can see more than 3 of them at a time. It's a horribly inefficient use of screen real estate in an already incredibly cluttered IDE.

Comment: oh sorry can't help u